# Django: rest api: Not recieving the complete json string when its very big

Tags: django, firefox

I am sending a very long json string using

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def sendlargedata(request):
   ....
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(all_graphs_data,default=str),status=200,content_type="application/json")
```

When i check the data in the firefox response it says

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 1048577 of the JSON data
```

so how to oversome any size or length restrictions and send the data and recieve

Answer (score 0):

Your default doesn't work in all the cases, I believe you have to escape too.